# Segment fault on thread_mutex_lock()

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, mutex

In my Producer/Consumer exercise, I want to build two threads, one for producer and the other one for the consumer.
They have access on a buffer for reading/writing messages on it, and i want use the mutex for manage this buffer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define BUFFER_LENGHT 10
#define BUFFER_ERROR (msg_t *) NULL
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

pthread_mutex_t printf_mutex;


typedef struct msg_t{
    void* content;

    struct msg_t* (*msg_init) (void*); 
    void (*msg_destroy) (struct msg_t*);
    struct msg_t* (*msg_copy)(struct msg_t*); 
}msg_t;

void msg_destroy(msg_t* msg){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&printf_mutex);
    printf("CONSUMER: Message deleted \n");
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&printf_mutex);
    free(msg);
}

struct msg_t* msg_copy(struct msg_t* message){
    struct msg_t* new_message;
    new_message = malloc(sizeof(msg_t));
    new_message->content = message->content;
    new_message->msg_copy = message->msg_copy;
    new_message->msg_destroy = message->msg_destroy;
    new_message->msg_init = message->msg_init;
    return new_message;
}

struct msg_t* msg_init(void* content){
    if(content != ""){
        struct msg_t* messaggio;
        messaggio = malloc(sizeof(msg_t));
        messaggio->content = content;
        messaggio->msg_init = msg_init;
        messaggio->msg_destroy = msg_destroy;
        messaggio->msg_copy = msg_copy;
        return messaggio;
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }
}

typedef struct buffer_t {

    int whereToWrite;
    int totMessagesToRead;
    int maxMsgs;
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;

    struct buffer_t* (*buffer_init) (unsigned int maxsize); 
    struct msg_t* (*put_bloccante)(struct buffer_t*, struct msg_t*); 

    struct msg_t* messaggio[];
}buffer_t;

_Bool bufferIsFull(buffer_t *buffer){
    int size = buffer->maxMsgs;
    int nToRead = buffer->totMessagesToRead;

    if(nToRead == size)
        return TRUE;
    else
        return FALSE;
}

struct msg_t* put_bloccante(struct buffer_t* buffer, struct msg_t* messaggio){
    struct msg_t* new_message;
    new_message = messaggio->msg_copy(messaggio);

    if(!bufferIsFull(buffer)){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&printf_mutex);
        printf("PRODUCER: Mutex enabled\n");
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&printf_mutex);

        pthread_mutex_lock(&(buffer->mutex));

        buffer->whereToWrite++;

        if(new_message == NULL){
            pthread_mutex_lock(&printf_mutex);
            printf("PRODUCER: Error on creating the message \n");
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&printf_mutex);
        } else{
            buffer->messaggio[buffer->whereToWrite] = new_message;
            buffer->totMessagesToRead++;
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&(buffer->mutex));

        pthread_mutex_lock(&printf_mutex);
        printf("PRODUCER: Mutex disabled\n");
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&printf_mutex);
    } else{
        pthread_mutex_lock(&printf_mutex);
        printf("PRODUCER: Buffer full... \n");
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&printf_mutex);
    }

    return new_message;
}

struct buffer_t* buffer_init (unsigned int maxsize){
    if(maxsize > 0){
        struct buffer_t* buffer;
        buffer = malloc(sizeof(struct buffer_t) + maxsize*sizeof(struct msg_t));
        buffer->whereToWrite = 0;
        buffer->maxMsgs = maxsize;
        buffer->totMessagesToRead = 0;
        buffer->put_bloccante = put_bloccante;

        pthread_mutex_init(&(buffer->mutex), NULL);

        return buffer;
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }

}

void sleep_random(char* whoCall){
    srand(time(NULL));
    int mills = rand() % 100+1; 

    pthread_mutex_lock(&printf_mutex);
    printf("%s: Waiting for %d milliseconds \n", whoCall, mills);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&printf_mutex);

    Sleep(mills);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&printf_mutex);
    printf("%s: Waiting finished \n", whoCall);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&printf_mutex);
}


void *consumatore(buffer_t *buffer){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&printf_mutex);
    printf("CONSUMER: Thread created\n");
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&printf_mutex);

    int life = 500;

    while(life > 0){
        life--;

        if(buffer->totMessagesToRead > 0){

            pthread_mutex_lock(&printf_mutex);
            printf("CONSUMER: mutex enabled\n");
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&printf_mutex);

            int whereToRead = (buffer->maxMsgs - (buffer->totMessagesToRead - buffer->whereToWrite)) % buffer->maxMsgs;

            pthread_mutex_lock(&printf_mutex);
            printf("CONSUMEr: Messagge recived: %s \n", (char *) buffer->messaggio[whereToRead]);
            printf("CONSUMER: The message is on the buffer position n. %d \n", whereToRead);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&printf_mutex);

            pthread_mutex_lock(&(buffer->mutex));

            buffer->messaggio[whereToRead]->msg_destroy(buffer->messaggio[whereToRead]);
            buffer->totMessagesToRead--;
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&(buffer->mutex));

            pthread_mutex_lock(&printf_mutex);
            printf("CONSUMER: mutex disabled\n");
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&printf_mutex);
            sleep_random("CONSUMER");

        } 
    }

}

void *produttore(buffer_t *buffer){
    void* messaggio;
    int life = 500;

    //Here I got the issue
    pthread_mutex_lock(&printf_mutex);
    printf("PRODUCER: Thread created\n");
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&printf_mutex);

    while(life > 0){
        messaggio = (rand() % 1000);

        struct msg_t  *msg_temp;
        msg_temp = malloc(sizeof( msg_t));
        msg_temp->msg_init = msg_init;
        msg_temp = msg_temp->msg_init(messaggio);
        msg_temp = put_bloccante(buffer, msg_temp);

        pthread_mutex_lock(&printf_mutex);
        printf("PRODUCER: There are %d messages to read \n", buffer->totMessagesToRead);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&printf_mutex);

        sleep_random("PRODUCER");
        life--;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    struct buffer_t *buffer, *buffer_temp;
    pthread_t pid_c, pid_p;
    int result_consumatore, result_produttore;

    pthread_mutex_init(&printf_mutex, NULL);


    buffer_temp = malloc(sizeof(buffer_t));
    buffer_temp->buffer_init = buffer_init;
    buffer_temp = buffer_temp->buffer_init(BUFFER_LENGHT);
    if(buffer_temp == NULL){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&printf_mutex);
        printf("PRODUCER: Error on buffer creation\n");
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&printf_mutex);
        return 0;
    }
    buffer = buffer_temp;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&printf_mutex);
    printf("MAIN: Buffer size %d \n", buffer_temp->maxMsgs);
    printf("MAIN: Current buffer position %d \n", buffer_temp->whereToWrite);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&printf_mutex);

    result_produttore = pthread_create(&pid_p, NULL, (void *) produttore, (void *) buffer);
    if(result_produttore != 0){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&printf_mutex);
        printf("MAIN: Error on producer thread creation, error: %d \n", result_produttore);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&printf_mutex);
        return 0;
    }

    result_consumatore = pthread_create(&pid_c, NULL, (void *) consumatore, (void *)buffer);
    if(result_consumatore != 0){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&printf_mutex);
        printf("MAIN: Error on consumer thread creation, error: %d \n", result_consumatore);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&printf_mutex);
        return 0;
    }

    pthread_join(pid_c, NULL);

}
```

If i run that code, I got a segment fault on the thread_mutex_loc(&printf_mutex) on the consumer thread, but my mutex is alredy initialized.

Comment: I would say the root of the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: That's not an MCVE, which makes this question off-topic. Also, those macros that you define are asking for trouble, so I'd fix those first.

Comment: Start deleting code until it goes away, and then start putting code back in until it manifests again. That'll help find the problem.

Comment: recommend getting rid of your `TRUE` and `FALSE` macros and `#include <stdbool.h>` instead

Comment: Also, 'buffer->totMessagesToRead' is used unprotected.  A mutex cannot 'manage' a PC queue, it can only protect it from multiple access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank for help, but I solved my issue.
My problem was in the variable whereToWrite, because it must points on the next empty element on the array, but in my code it points on the last element added, so when I tried to read with this code:

```
int whereToRead = (buffer->maxMsgs - (buffer->totMessagesToRead - buffer->whereToWrite)) % buffer->maxMsgs;
```

whereToRead points on an empty location, so I changed this lines in put_bloccante:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&(buffer->mutex));

    buffer->whereToWrite++;

    if(new_message == NULL){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&printf_mutex);
        printf("PRODUCER: Error on creating the message \n");
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&printf_mutex);
    } else{
        buffer->messaggio[buffer->whereToWrite] = new_message;
        buffer->totMessagesToRead++;
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&(buffer->mutex));
```

with this code:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&(buffer->mutex));

        if(new_message == NULL){
            pthread_mutex_lock(&printf_mutex);
            printf("PRODUCER: Error on creating the message \n");
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&printf_mutex);
        } else{
            buffer->messaggio[buffer->whereToWrite] = new_message;
            buffer->totMessagesToRead++;
            buffer->whereToWrite++;
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&(buffer->mutex));
```

Answer (score 0):

Buonjorno fratello!
The main problem (amongst others)of your code was that thread

> void *consumatore

doesn't have any pthread_exit() implementation (productore also).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define BUFFER_LENGHT 10
#define BUFFER_ERROR (msg_t *) NULL
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

pthread_mutex_t printf_mutex;


typedef struct msg_t{
    void* content;

    struct msg_t* (*msg_init) (void*);
    void (*msg_destroy) (struct msg_t*);
    struct msg_t* (*msg_copy)(struct msg_t*);
}msg_t;

void msg_destroy(msg_t* msg){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&printf_mutex);
    printf("CONSUMER: Message deleted \n");
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&printf_mutex);
    free(msg);
}

struct msg_t* msg_copy(struct msg_t* message){
    struct msg_t* new_message;
    new_message = malloc(sizeof(msg_t));
    new_message->content = message->content;
    new_message->msg_copy = message->msg_copy;
    new_message->msg_destroy = message->msg_destroy;
    new_message->msg_init = message->msg_init;
    return new_message;
}

struct msg_t* msg_init(void* content){
    if(content != NULL){
        struct msg_t* messaggio;
        messaggio = malloc(sizeof(msg_t));
        messaggio->content = content;
        messaggio->msg_init = msg_init;
        messaggio->msg_destroy = msg_destroy;
        messaggio->msg_copy = msg_copy;
        return messaggio;
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }
}

typedef struct buffer_t {

    int whereToWrite;
    int totMessagesToRead;
    int maxMsgs;
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;

    struct buffer_t* (*buffer_init) (unsigned int maxsize);
    struct msg_t* (*put_bloccante)(struct buffer_t*, struct msg_t*);

    struct msg_t* messaggio[];
}buffer_t;

_Bool bufferIsFull(buffer_t *buffer){
    int size = buffer->maxMsgs;
    int nToRead = buffer->totMessagesToRead;

    if(nToRead == size)
        return TRUE;
    else
        return FALSE;
}

struct msg_t* put_bloccante(struct buffer_t* buffer, struct msg_t* messaggio){
    struct msg_t* new_message;
    new_message = messaggio->msg_copy(messaggio);

    if(!bufferIsFull(buffer)){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&printf_mutex);
        printf("PRODUCER: Mutex enabled\n");
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&printf_mutex);

        pthread_mutex_lock(&(buffer->mutex));

        buffer->whereToWrite++;

        if(new_message == NULL){
            pthread_mutex_lock(&printf_mutex);
            printf("PRODUCER: Error on creating the message \n");
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&printf_mutex);
        } else{
            buffer->messaggio[buffer->whereToWrite] = new_message;
            buffer->totMessagesToRead++;
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&(buffer->mutex));

        pthread_mutex_lock(&printf_mutex);
        printf("PRODUCER: Mutex disabled\n");
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&printf_mutex);
    } else{
        pthread_mutex_lock(&printf_mutex);
        printf("PRODUCER: Buffer full... \n");
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&printf_mutex);
    }

    return new_message;
}

struct buffer_t* buffer_init (unsigned int maxsize){
    if(maxsize > 0){
        struct buffer_t* buffer;
        buffer = malloc(sizeof(struct buffer_t) + maxsize*sizeof(struct msg_t));
        buffer->whereToWrite = 0;
        buffer->maxMsgs = maxsize;
        buffer->totMessagesToRead = 0;
        buffer->put_bloccante = put_bloccante;

        pthread_mutex_init(&(buffer->mutex), NULL);

        return buffer;
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }

}

void sleep_random(char* whoCall){
    srand(time(NULL));
    int mills = rand() % 100+1;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&printf_mutex);
    printf("%s: Waiting for %d milliseconds \n", whoCall, mills);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&printf_mutex);

    sleep(mills);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&printf_mutex);
    printf("%s: Waiting finished \n", whoCall);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&printf_mutex);
}


void *consumatore(buffer_t *buffer){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&printf_mutex);
    printf("CONSUMER: Thread created\n");
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&printf_mutex);

    int life = 500;

    while(life > 0){
        life--;

        if(buffer->totMessagesToRead > 0){

            pthread_mutex_lock(&printf_mutex);
            printf("CONSUMER: mutex enabled\n");
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&printf_mutex);

            int whereToRead = (buffer->maxMsgs - (buffer->totMessagesToRead - buffer->whereToWrite)) % buffer->maxMsgs;

            pthread_mutex_lock(&printf_mutex);
            printf("CONSUMEr: Messagge recived: %s \n", (char *) buffer->messaggio[whereToRead]);
            printf("CONSUMER: The message is on the buffer position n. %d \n", whereToRead);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&printf_mutex);

            pthread_mutex_lock(&(buffer->mutex));

            buffer->messaggio[whereToRead]->msg_destroy(buffer->messaggio[whereToRead]);
            buffer->totMessagesToRead--;
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&(buffer->mutex));

            pthread_mutex_lock(&printf_mutex);
            printf("CONSUMER: mutex disabled\n");
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&printf_mutex);
            sleep_random("CONSUMER");

        }
    }
    pthread_exit(0);
}

void *produttore(buffer_t *buffer){
    int* messaggio;
    int life = 500;

    //Here I got the issue
    pthread_mutex_lock(&printf_mutex);
    printf("PRODUCER: Thread created\n");
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&printf_mutex);

    while(life > 0){
        messaggio =(rand() % 1000);

        struct msg_t  *msg_temp;
        msg_temp = malloc(sizeof( msg_t));
        msg_temp->msg_init = msg_init;
        msg_temp = msg_temp->msg_init(messaggio);
        msg_temp = put_bloccante(buffer, msg_temp);

        pthread_mutex_lock(&printf_mutex);
        printf("PRODUCER: There are %d messages to read \n", buffer->totMessagesToRead);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&printf_mutex);

        sleep_random("PRODUCER");
        life--;
    }
    pthread_exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    struct buffer_t *buffer, *buffer_temp;
    pthread_t pid_c, pid_p;
    int result_consumatore, result_produttore;

    pthread_mutex_init(&printf_mutex, NULL);


    buffer_temp = malloc(sizeof(buffer_t));
    buffer_temp->buffer_init = buffer_init;
    buffer_temp = buffer_temp->buffer_init(BUFFER_LENGHT);
    if(buffer_temp == NULL){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&printf_mutex);
        printf("PRODUCER: Error on buffer creation\n");
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&printf_mutex);
        return 0;
    }
    buffer = buffer_temp;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&printf_mutex);
    printf("MAIN: Buffer size %d \n", buffer_temp->maxMsgs);
    printf("MAIN: Current buffer position %d \n", buffer_temp->whereToWrite);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&printf_mutex);

    result_produttore = pthread_create(&pid_p, NULL, (void *) produttore, (void *) buffer);
    if(result_produttore != 0){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&printf_mutex);
        printf("MAIN: Error on producer thread creation, error: %d \n", result_produttore);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&printf_mutex);
        return 0;
    }

    result_consumatore = pthread_create(&pid_c, NULL, (void *) consumatore, (void *)buffer);
    if(result_consumatore != 0){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&printf_mutex);
        printf("MAIN: Error on consumer thread creation, error: %d \n", result_consumatore);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&printf_mutex);
        return 0;
    }

    pthread_join(pid_c, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```